# AngularJS hide and show a char

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers, chart.js, ng-hide

I am trying to show a chart only when a user presses a button! Currently I am making the following :

In the html:

```
<canvas ng-hide="secondGraph" id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" ng-click="secondGraphCtrl()"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Second Graph</button>
```

In the controllers.js:

```
$scope.secondGraphCtrl = function() {
        if($scope.secondGraph==true)
            $scope.secondGraph=false;
        else
            $scope.secondGraph=true;
    }
```

But the graph never shows... My $scope.secondGraph starts = true

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could simplify this by binding `ng-hide` to the value `secondGraph`. Have `ng-click` simply set `secondGraph = !secondGraph`, right there in the html.

Comment: Is your function definitely being executed?

Comment: Yes, it is net.uk.sweet. I made alerts to verify that. It shows nothing, only the series text appear

Comment: If I start with the graphs visible I can hide them simply by pressing the button. But if I start with them hidden I can only see the series text, and no graphs appear

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not using any angular directive for Chart.js (from the SO tags). If so, you need to draw the line only after the Chart.js canvas is visible. So wrap the `$scope.secondGraph=false;` in a block and put the `var cts=... ; new Chart(ctx).Bar...;`  right after that.

Fiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/pbog134e/

Also looking at your HTML, if you dynamically want the chart to update, you either have to watch the data and labels or use something like http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: Didn't understand that well @potatopeelings, what do you mean?

Comment: Check out the fiddle that I just added

Answer (score 0):

You are using simple canvas bit do you if Angular is aware of your chart present on the page?  It's not!

Best approach would be to try to bring charts into Angular eco system  i.e. either write your own chart directives or use a angular chart library..

Check this :
http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/